# Mysql count not working?

Tags: mysql

I have a query

```
SELECT 
count(*) as count 
from matches 
WHERE team1 = 9 
ORDER BY data DESC, id ASC LIMIT 10
```

The max result I should expect isn't supposed to be 10? I am getting 15 as result, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: try `SELECT count(*) from matches WHERE team1 = 9 ORDER BY data DESC, id ASC LIMIT 10`

Comment: Is it possible to have an alias count? if it's a reserve word in mysql

Comment: It is fine to use `count` as a field alias. It's the name of a function, not actually a reserved word ("SELECT" is a reserved word).

Comment: @plain jane, still got 15 as result :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do your limit in an inner select.

```
select count(*) from
(select * from matches WHERE team1 = 9 ORDER BY data DESC, id ASC LIMIT 10) ten_rows
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11c94/1)

Answer (score 1):

The `LIMIT 10` clause applies *after* the `SELECT ...` part of the query. So it's counting the rows and putting that number into a single row before applying `LIMIT 10`.

If you were using the API and asking it how many rows there were in a resultset, then you would indeed get the reply of 10 from the query `SELECT * FROM ... LIMIT 10`.

Answer (score 1):

You are just get the `count` values, `limit` is not supposed to work for you count rows.

Using `LIMIT` you will not limit the count or sum but only the returned rows.

In other words, It counts no.of records from table and returned as single row. Your select query matched rows count is **15**.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this,

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS COUNT 
FROM matches 
WHERE team1 = 9 
ORDER BY DATA DESC, id ASC
```